# Как сделать кнопки без фона

Tags: android, android-button

Хочу сделать свой `CardView` по прототипу такого как на скриншоте (будет ниже).
 Основная проблема заключается в том, что кнопки которые расположены внизу не похожи на обычные, они скорее очень похожи на такие как в Action и Tool барах.
Но как сделать такие в `CardView` я не знаю, подскажите.

P.S.: Такими кнопками здесь являются кнопки READ и кнопка вызова меню.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: о выпадении списка при нажатии на кнопку задавайте новый вопрос. В одном вопросе может быть только одна проблема

Comment: TextView и слушатель

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить такие кнопки нужно просто указать стили к обычным виджетам:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/read_button"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:text="@string/read_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`CardView` - это обычный `ViewGroup` в который вы можете положите разные `View` и другие `ViewGroup` (`LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` и др). Эти кнопки можно сделать положив в `CardView` `TextView` и `ImageView`. Картинка с тремя вертикальными точками есть стандартная в андроиде(не помню как называется)

Comment: Если вы положите туда простой textview, при касании, цвет его фона меняться не будет

Comment: Ну так это настраиваемая вещь. Я не вижу в этом проблемы