# Нет реакции на касание по Button

Tags: android, android-button

Я решил сделать кнопку, но я захотел сделать ее не стандартной, а такого же стиля как и в ToolBar, т.е. что бы у нее не было никакого фона. И столкнулся с такой проблемой, что она никак не реагирует на касание, т.е. если кнопки в ToolBar при касании анимированно выделяются, то моя - нет. Подскажите, как мне это пофиксить?

код разметки для кнопки:

```
<Button
                        android:text="@string/read"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:id="@+id/read_Btn"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:textColorHighlight="@color/Black"/>
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/631123/177345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй это

```
 android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

вместо

```
   android:background="@null"
```

Или вот так можно сделать эффект для Lolipop и выше

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/yourninepatch" />
</ripple>
```

Ниже способ для всех версий андроид. Собственно что я и написал в самом начале. Но если вдруг так получилось что вы создаете кнопку программно, а сделать ее прозрачной с эффектом нажания очень хочется, то используйте этот селектор.

Использование: button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.название селектора ниже).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">
</selector>
```

Comment: А с API<Lollipop как это работать будет?

Comment: @Ник отредактировал ответ

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы кнопка "анимировалась" при касании, необходимо сделать селектор, который будет обрабатывать состояния.

1. Подготовьте **drawable** ресурсы, который будут показаны при различных состояниях кнопки. Например, `read_btn_normal.xml` и `read_btn_pressed.xml`
2. В папке drawable создаёте файл `read_btn_selector.xml`
3. В файле селектора создаёте запись следующего вида:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/read_btn_pressed" />
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/read_btn_normal" />
   </selector>`
4. Установите для кнопки данный селектор -

   `android:background="@drawable/read_btn_selector"`